# How to pass query parameter and class attribute to Html.BeginForm in MVC3?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-helper

I'm a little bit confused with Html helpers in MVC3.

I used this syntax when creating my forms before:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("action", "controller", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "auth-form" })) { ... }
```

this gives me

```
<form action="/controller/action" class="auth-form" method="post">...</form>
```

fine, that's what I needed then.

Now I need to pass ReturnUrl parameter to the form, so I can do it like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("action", "controller", new { ReturnUrl="myurl" } )) { ... }
```

that would give me

```
<form action="/controller/action?ReturnUrl=myurl" method="post"></form>
```

but I still need to pass css class and id to this form and I can't find the way to do it simultaneously passing ReturnUrl parameter.

If I add `FormMethod.Post` it adds all my parameters as attributes to the form tag, without `FormMethod.Post` it adds them as query string parameters.

How do I do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("action", "controller", new { ReturnUrl="myurl" }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "auth-form" })) { ... }
```

this will give:

```
<form action="/controller/action?ReturnUrl=myurl" class="auth-form" method="post">
   ...
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks pjumble, that is what I need. Didn't try to put ReturnUrl before `FormMethod.Post`. A little bit of magic is happening there, difficult to figure it out without someone's help.

Answer (score 3):

1-Harder way: define routeValues externally and then use the variable

```
@{
    var routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary();
    routeValues.Add("UserId", "5");
    // you can read the current QueryString from URL with equest.QueryString["userId"]
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", routeValues))
{
    @Html.TextBox("Name");
    @Html.Password("Password");
    <input type="submit" value="Sign In">
}
// Produces the following form element
// <form action="/Account/Login?UserId=5" action="post">
```

2- simpler inline way: Use the Route value internally with Razor

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { UserId = "5" }, FormMethod.Post, new { Id = "Form1" }))
{
    @Html.TextBox("Name");
    @Html.Password("Password");
    <input type="submit" value="Sign In">
}
// Produces the following form element
// <form Id="Form1" action="/Account/Login?UserId=5" action="post">
```

Just note that in case you want to add post (FormMethod.Post) or get explicitly it comes after routeValues parameter

[official source with good examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx)